# Можно ли передавать RTSP видео поток из андроида на URL а не на IP

Tags: java, android, rtsp

Использую одну либу для передачи видео по rtsp.Есть такая строка конекшна

```
public static final String STREAM_URL = "rtsp://127.0.0.1:5555/stream";
```

можно ли вместо этого использовать :

```
public static final String STREAM_URL = "rtsp://livestream/stream";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно, если в DNS прописано что имя livestream соответствует нужному IP ресурса, и ресурс слушает порт 554 (порт по умолчанию для протокола rtsp).